# How to display the selected value in dropdown after navigating to another html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown

My application consists of 4 roles which will be in dropdown menu. If I click on a particular role, it will navigate to the mentioned href link which I have mentioned. 
My problem is after navigating to the second html page, the role was not fixed in the dropdown. It keeps on showing the first value only.
       My first html:

```
     <select name="loginuser" id="loginuser">
       <option value="dash.html">first</option>
       <option value="dash1.html">second</option>
       <option value="dash2.html">third</option>
     </select>

  jquery:
     <script>
         $("#loginuser").change(function () {
         url = this.value;
         if (url !== "") {
            window.location = url;
          }
         });
      <script>
```

My Second html file:

```
        <select name="loginuser" id="loginuser">
       <option value="dash.html">first</option>
       <option value="dash1.html">second</option>
       <option value="dash2.html">third</option>
     </select>

  jquery:
     <script>
         $("#loginuser").change(function () {
         url = this.value;
         if (url !== "") {
            window.location = url;
          }
         });
      <script>
```

Comment: A page refresh (triggered by `window.location`) resets the page's state. You need to save the page's state, probably, by using [LocalStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: @31piy that “state” is identical with the current URL though here I’d say, so checking `location.href` on page load should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second page should show the selected value by using the simple standard that HTML has.  How you do that may be stored somehow or placed within the page server side using a passed parameter to the URL, that choice is somewhat your choice how to propagate that state.

```js
$("#loginuser").change(function() {
  url = this.value;
  if (url !== "") {
    window.location = url;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="loginuser" id="loginuser">
  <option value="dash.html">first</option>
  <option value="dash1.html" selected="selected">second</option>
  <option value="dash2.html">third</option>
</select>
```

As ONE way to do this, you can use the current pages location to set the selected.

```js
$("#loginuser").change(function() {
  url = this.value;
  if (url !== "") {
    window.location = url;
  }
});
$(function() {
 let current = window.location.href;
  $('#loginuser').find('option').each(function() {
    let optionvalue = $(this).val();
    let current = window.location.href;
    console.log(current);
    let isThisPage =(current.indexOf(optionvalue) > -1);
    $(this).prop("selected", isThisPage);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="loginuser" id="loginuser">
  <option value="dash.html">first</option>
  <option value="dash1.html" selected="selected">second</option>
  <option value="dash2.html">third</option>
  <option value="stacksnippets.net">thispage</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I added ONE way to do that dynamically, another may be to pass or save the option selected or that index of said option (if they all stay in the same order).